# Regex 2 groups of characters with question mark quantifier, one of them has to be used

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have this pattern for my regex parsing:

`string pattern = "([ABEFGIJKLMNOPQRTUVabefgijklmnopqrtuv23456789\\*]?[CDHSWXYZcdhswxyz]?)";`

The problem is that it accepts empty string as well, which I do not want. I want the pattern modified so that at least one of the groups has to be used (or that the whole pattern is at least one character).

EDIT: It needs to be matches with either 1 character from one of the groups or 2 characters, one from each.

Thank you for help,
Joe

Comment: Perhaps you should start by explaining what's the effect that you wish to achieve - what strings you wish to accept, what strings you want to reject, and so on.

Comment: Just added that info, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use look-ahead to make sure there is at least one character, so it won't match empty strings. Simply add (?=.) in front of the regex.

```
(?=.)([ABEFGIJKLMNOPQRTUVabefgijklmnopqrtuv23456789\\*]?[CDHSWXYZcdhswxyz]?)
```

This will now match at least one of the character classes, so no empty strings.

Answer (score -1):

Off the top of my head here buy i think:

```
(?=\w)([ABC]?[DEF]?)
```

Should do it

Comment: That will match 2 characters from the same group.